# A group of all whose elements are distorted

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

> Does there exist a finitely presented group, not torsion, all of whose infinite-order elements are distorted?

An infinite-order element $g$ of a finitely generated group $G$ is *undistorted* if there exist constants $A,B \geq 1$ such that $\|g^n\|_S \geq \frac{n}{A}  -B$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $\| \cdot \|_S$ denotes the word length associated to a fixed finite generating set $S$ of $G$. An element which is not undistorted is *distorted*.

I am mainly interested in the finitely presented case, but a finitely generated example would be interesting as well.

**Edit:** I realised that a finitely generated example exists as a consequence of Osin's paper *[Small cancellations over relatively hyperbolic groups and embedding theorems](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411039)*. (Since an infinite-order element which is conjugate to its square is necessarily distorted.)

Comment: What if all elements have finite order?

Comment: More generally, a finitely generated subgroup $H \leq G$ is *undistorted* or *quasi-isometrically embedded* if the inclusion $H \hookrightarrow G$ induces a quasi-isometric embedding when $H$ and $G$ are both endowed with a word metric associated to a finite generating set. So finite-order elements are always undistorted.

Comment: I mean, there exist countable finitely generated groups in which all elements have finite order, does it answer your question (for finitely generated groups)?

Comment: No, I am really interested in infinite-order elements.

Comment: A small observation: product of two distorted elements is again distorted. Therefore if you consider the set of all distorted elements, its a subgroup of the original group. I guess the hard part is to check whether it is finitely generated or not.

Comment: The product a distorted element with its inverse is $1$. How is $1$ distorted?

Comment: In my sense, elements of finite order are distorted (they have the largest possible distortion, namely infinite), while finite cyclic subgroups are undistorted.

Comment: The question is among those many open questions about finitely presented groups.

Comment: @AGenevois $||1^n||_S=2$ for all $n$. Therefore it is distorted.

Comment: @tessellation Why is the product of two distorted elements also distorted ?